# Xamarin.Android app crashes with NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project that is crashing the second time that the page is rendered with the following error message:

```
**System.NotSupportedException:** 'Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageButtonRenderer from native handle 0x7fe2d1b234 (key_handle 0x3fea9eb).'

04-14 10:34:05.676 E/mono    ( 9225): 
04-14 10:34:05.676 E/mono    ( 9225): Unhandled Exception:
04-14 10:34:05.676 E/mono    ( 9225): System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageButtonRenderer from native handle 0x7fe2d1b234 (key_handle 0x3fea9eb). ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageButtonRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
```

The strange thing is that the page loads perfectly the first time that you access it.  It is only when you navigate away from the page and then back to the page where it crashes with this error.

I have a view model that binds to a Syncfusion SfListView.  One of those elements inside that listview is an Image.  Here is the layout code that I think is relevant:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <syncfusion2:SfPullToRefresh.PullableContent>
        <syncfusion:SfListView AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight">
            <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewLayout">
                            <Image 
                                Source="{Binding CameraSnapshot}" 
                                Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                WidthRequest="300" 
                                HeightRequest="200"
                                Visual="CustomImageVisual"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        </syncfusion:SfListView>
    </syncfusion2:SfPullToRefresh>
</Grid>
```

After I pull a list of the cameras, I set the ItemSource of my listview to a list of my camera models, and then I call a method within each view item to initiate a snapshot pull from each camera:

```
foreach (CameraViewModel camera in Cameras)
{
    camera.StartStatusThread();
}
```

Then, inside my CameraViewModel object (which is bound to the listview):

```
public async void StartStatusThread()
{
    ImageSource source = await CameraCommands.GetSnapshot(this);
    if (source != null)
    {
        CameraSnapshot = source;
    }
    else
    {
        CameraSnapshot = "nocamera.png";
    }
}

public ImageSource CameraSnapshot
{
    get
    {
        return snapshot;
    }
    set
    {
        snapshot = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CameraSnapshot"));
    }
}
```

The function `CameraCommands.GetSnapshot(...)` uses the camera configuration and uses some Rtsp libraries to return a byte[] array of a snapshot from a camera and sets the source using `source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));`

Making this even stranger, the actual error is thrown below (this is inside GetSnapshot(...)

```
byte[] bytes = null;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   try
   {
      if (basicAuth != null)
      {
         client.Headers.Add("Authorization", basicAuth);
      }

      // error is thrown here...
      bytes = client.DownloadData(new Uri(link));
   }
   catch { }
   finally
   {
      client.Dispose();
   }
}
source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

What would a rest call to retrieve data have to do with rendering an Image???

Again, this all works perfectly as expected the first time that I go to this page.  But the second time I go to this page, the error is thrown.  So something must not be disposed of properly, but I can't think of what that could be.

I am open to any suggestions that anybody has to resolve.

Thanks!

** updated **
I tried adding a custom ImageRenderer as suggested:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Image), typeof(Voltsec.Droid.Renderers.CustomImageRenderer), new[] { typeof(CustomImageVisual) })]
namespace Voltsec.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomImageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.ImageRenderer
    {
        public CustomImageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        { }

        [Obsolete]
        public CustomImageRenderer(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        { }
    }
}
```

It immediately throws this error as soon as I go to that page:

`System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'Voltsec.Droid.Renderers.CustomImageRenderer' not found.'`

Comment: Try to disable the fastrenderer to see if it could work. In your Mainactivity add `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");` before `Forms.Init`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But that didn't appear to make any difference.  Still crashes as mentioned above.

Comment: Do you use any other nuget ? Such as MvvmCross.

Comment: No sorry I am not familiar with MvvmCross.

Comment: Try to create a custom ImageRenderer,then add a constructor,like [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8262#issuecomment-550022425)

Comment: It gives me this error as soon as I open the page: System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'Voltsec.Droid.Renderers.CustomImageRenderer' not found.'

Comment: I added the custom renderer to my original post so you can see it there...

Comment: I added a little more information to the original post.

Comment: Could you share a simplified project ？

Comment: It turns out there is a bug in the latest release of Xamarin.Forms.  Creating a custom imagebutton renderer did in fact solve the problem as a workaround. Thanks!